# Has the Core Data database persistent storage location changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, core-data, persistent-storage

I was getting the persistent storage error that has been reported by many others.  However in my case it was not due to changing the database model.  I chased that rabbit for a couple of hours.  Finally one post lead me to try and delete the database itself.  I went to the directory my URL pointed to

url=/Users/ccox/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/8A231E05-B3A2-4E83-8C81-6B3989C262A5/Library/Documentation/DBEViewDocumentand

it didn't exist.
url=/Users/ccox/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/8A231E05-B3A2-4E83-8C81-6B3989C262A5/Library/

was there but the Documentation directory was not there.

Here is the code I am using to get the URL

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *documentsDirectory =[[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentationDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSString *documentName = @"DBEViewDocument";
self.url = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:self.url];
NSLog(@"url=%@",[self.url path]);
```

The output from the NSLog is the output URL above.

Is there a setting somewhere that sets the destination location for that documents directory?  Apparently the Documentation directory is a not a standard directory since it's not created as part of the application install.

I went ahead and created the Documentation directory and now everything is working fine (at least that far), but I can't believe this is by design and that everyone is having to do this.

Any thoughts?
Thanks
Chip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong directory. `NSDocumentationDirectory` is not a standard location for documents, and is not created by default. You want `NSDocumentDirectory`, which **is** created by default.

Comment: Thanks  I'm going from lecture slides and typing them in instead of just cutting and pasting.  Sometimes I guess I rely a little to much on autocomplete.  LOL  Thanks again